# Python global name not defined error?

Tags: python, regex

I am calling a function to validate form in python, but I am getting error :

> user = valid_username(username)
>     NameError: global name 'valid_username' is not defined.

code:

```
class MainPage(Handler):
def valid_username(self,username):
    print USER_RE.match(username)
    return USER_RE.match(username)

def render_front(self,username="",password="",error=""):
    logins = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM logindb")
    self.render("login.html",username=username,password=password,error=error,logins=logins)

def get(self):
    self.render_front()

def post(self):
    username = self.request.get("userID")
    password = self.request.get("pass")
    user = valid_username(username)
    # pas = isvalid_password(password)
    if user and password:
        a = logindb(username = username,password=password)
        a.put()
        self.redirect("/")
    else:
        error = "we need both username and password"
        self.render_front(username,password,error)
```

Comment: That's not the error you're getting. Copy and paste instead of retyping from memory.

Comment: I am using google app engine my error is as follows:user = valid_username(username)
NameError: global name 'valid_username' is not defined

Comment: The 2nd function is from a class defn ??

Comment: yes, both are from the same class.

Comment: The example you show us doesn't have any classes so _"both are from the same class"_ makes no sense. If these are class methods, you likely want to use `user = self.valid_username(username)`. Please post a minimal example that shows the error.

Comment: class MainPage(Handler):
        def valid_username(self,username):
            print USER_RE.match(username)
            return USER_RE.match(username)

Comment: Its better to edit the original question and put this in a code block so we can see indentations and etc...

Comment: def post(self):
        username = self.request.get("userID")
        password = self.request.get("pass")
        user = valid_username(username)
        # pas = isvalid_password(password)
        if user and password:
            a = logindb(username = username,password=password)
            a.put()
            self.redirect("/")
        else:
            error = "we need both username and password"
            self.render_front(username,password,error)

Comment: yeah, I edited the question

Comment: Is the lack of indentation inside the class a cut+paste issue or do you really not have any?

Comment: Thanks! Its a class method so call it the way I mentioned... `user = self.valid_username(username)`

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot @tdelaney

Answer (score 0):

`valid_username` is a class method which means that its name is in the class namespace. But python doesn't look variables up in the class namespace unless you explicitly tell it to do so. When python sees:

```
    user = valid_username(username)
```

it looks for `"valid_username"` in the local method scope and then the module scope (confusingly called "global"). Since its not in either, you get the error.

When you define a class method like:

```
    def valid_username(self,username):
```

the `self` variable is in the local function scope and refers to the class instance data. You use `self` to find the method:

```
    user = self.valid_username(username)
```

Now, python looks up `self` in the local function scope, realizes its a class instance reference, and continues the lookup by first checking if the name is in the instance variables and then falling back to the class namespace (finally!) where your method is defined.